# get youtube video tags using youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm creating a page were i show users list of all videos that i have uploaded in my youtube account. I'm using Youtube API (gdata) for fetching the videos, but whatever i do i'm not able to fetch the tags details of the videos.

In one of [youtube's blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html) its been mentioned that tags (keywords) would no longer be shown in the youtube Data API (without any authentication). So I created a developer key, but even after using the developer key Im not able to get the video tags (keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Are not these the keywords in the single video Data, take a look at: [YouTube API v2.0 – Retrieving Data for a Single Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries?hl=en) and [Understanding Video feeds and Entries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds#Understanding_Video_Entries) and try to search [this site](http://gdata-samples-youtube-search-py.appspot.com/) for the word `tags`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Here check the youtube data api feed (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ineelq/uploads/Jx7ARa2yiV8?v=2)   In the feed u can see the keyword tag is always blank

Answer (score 0):

The blog entry states that not only do you have to be authenticated, but you can only get keywords if the videos are "*owned by the currently authorized user*".

So the keywords can only be fetched by the same ID that uploaded the videos.